# How logout the Facebook using storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I call:

```
    [[FacebookRequests sharedInstance] facebookLogout];
```

What contain:

```
     [FBSession.activeSession close];
     [FBSession.activeSession  closeAndClearTokenInformation];
     FBSession.activeSession = nil;
```

And got error, but I quit Facebook, that is wrong?

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x10a441660 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2500;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
```

}}

UPDATE

I fixes it, after my

```
 [FBSession.activeSession close];
 [FBSession.activeSession  closeAndClearTokenInformation];
 FBSession.activeSession = nil;\
```

automatically called part of facebookLogin from block ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) , and it tried to get info where I still not have active scission, so i add 'if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)' and error not comes anymore

```
- (void)facebookLogin
{
 if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
{
     NSLog(@"fb session opened");
} else   {
     [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_birthday", @"email"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
         }
           if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
         [self getPermissions];
          }
          [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

delete all cookie and caches storage

more information [login-tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial)

[sample Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/sample-apps)

```
-(void) faceBookLogout
    {

        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (cookie in [storage cookies])
        {
            NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
            NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
            if(domainRange.length > 0)
            {
                [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
            }
        }
    }
```